# Evaluate limit approaching (a,b) using polar coordinates

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I know how to use polar coordinates to evaluate a limit where $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$. But how do I do it if $(x,y)$ approaches a different point than $(0,0)$?

I thought of perhaps still using that $(r \to 0)$ but when I translate the function use that

$r^2=(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2$

$x = r \cos(\theta) + a$

$y = r \sin(\theta) + b$

(Assuming that $(x,y)$ approaches $(a,b)$)

Would that give me a correct answer?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: The question is not so bad, the downvote is probably due to the MathJax. (I am not the downvoter). If you rewrite formulas properly I will gladly upvote your question.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE ! In your question, you mention the use of polar coordinates to evaluate a limit at (0,0) in cartesian coordinates. However, you provide no examples. In order to clarify your question, you should show in detail what you have done, using a specific example seems to me, in this case, the best approach.

Comment: @AnnikaS Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

We can simply take $(x,y)=(u+a,v+b)$ with $(u,v)\to (0,0)$ and then use polar coordinates for $u$ and $v$ that is precisely equivalent to your way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your idea of  $$ x=a+ r\cos \theta, y=b+r\sin \theta $$ works fine.

Go for it.

Comment: Thank you for your help!